# How to align center a row with a text that wraps using TailwindCSS?

Tags: html, css, alignment, tailwind-css, flex3

I have a problem using TailwindCSS to align center some elements in a `flex-row` as soon as the text in the row item starts to get longer and wrap.

Here is my current implementation:

```html
<div class="border-1 p-2 flex w-[250px] flex-col items-center rounded border border-solid border-gray-300">
  <div class="flex flex-row">
    <div>UUID</div>
    <div class="ml-2">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-2">
    2023-10-23
  </div>
</div>
```

It displays as I want if the text does not wrap:

[image]

https://play.tailwindcss.com/UEGaldW7eo

However when the text get's bigger and starts to wrap, then the row (UUID + text) is no longer center aligned.

[image]

What I'd like is that:

[image]
[image]

But I can't make it work somehow.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set "w-min" to the div that contains the text so that wenn the text starts wrapping its div width shrinks to a minimum width.

```html
<div class="border-1 p-2 flex w-[250px] flex-col items-center rounded border border-solid border-gray-300">
  <div class="flex flex-row">
    <div>UUID</div>
    <div class="ml-2 w-min">MyTextThat wrapsOnTwoLines</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-2">2023-10-23</div>
</div>
```

Which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The probable issue is due to the line-break that in utrn breaks `flex-alignment`. I used `items-center` and `text-start` classes to try to achieve the layout that you're expecting. Something like:

```html
<div class="flex flex-col items-center text-start">
    <div class="flex flex-row items-start justify-center">
      <div class="pl-4">UUID</div>
      <div class="ml-2">
        Text that is long enough to wrap on 2 lines and more
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/os8qu5FYcY)***

Comment: Thanks for your proposal and help. I'm not sure however it's doing what I want. For example in such case, the text is not well centered:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/zxJRWO3ou4
I don't want to play with the padding/margin left of the div with UUID to have it center aligned.

Comment: @skuallpa ok so you want the whole content inside the card to be centered right? The same that you added in the expected image above? You're expecting something like this?https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZTD5ORnHrH

Comment: Not exactly. This is what I get with your proposal:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/wpDbiHpR59
I've added a new screenshot of what I'd like in the original question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCQoe.png

Comment: @skuallpa, it has to do with the width class I believe. The items are in center only but since the width is `250px` we're not able to see them. Try increasing the width and check once

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried increasing the width of the outer div. https://play.tailwindcss.com/3Lzk5jJu2Y
The text on the right is well centered but why does its div expand to full width causing the UUID div to shrink and be left align: https://imgur.com/FjruGK9. I'd like both elements to be centered, like this: https://imgur.com/1LCdRGk

Comment: OK I finally found the solution. I needed to add "w-min" to the div which contains the text that wraps so that its width shrinks. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @skuallpa cool. great work all the best. +1 to your answer. Also don't forget to accept your answer so it stays on top and suggest the future readers